# Waiting async/await function totally

Tags: flutter, dart

In the beginning of system ,I need to load the xml file.

I use `async`/`await` to wait for `rootBundle.loadString` finish.

However in this case, `print ("I can wait rootBundle here");` is executed after `rootBundle.loadString` finish, `runApp(MyApp())` starts before finished.

Is there a way to execute `runApp()` after  `rootBundle.loadString` finish

Because my whole setting is written in one xml files. so I want to make sure to load before first building.

```
void main(){
  inter = new Internationalize();
  inter.init();
  runApp(MyApp());
}


class Internationalize{
  var intls = {};
  var xmlBody;
  void init(){
    print("internationalize class start");
    rootBundle.loadString('assets/i18n/en/strings.xml').then(
      (String contents) {
      var document = xml.parse(contents);
      xmlBody = document.findAllElements('string');
      print("load finish");
    });
    print ("I can wait rootBundle here");
  }
}
```

Comment: Do let me know if the solution didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() async { // mark it async
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // mandatory since Flutter 1.9 if you're making this method async

  inter = new Internationalize();
  await inter.init(); // await here
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class Internationalize {
  var intls = {};
  var xmlBody;

  Future<void> init() async { // make it Future<void>
    print("internationalize class start");
    String contents = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/i18n/en/strings.xml'); // await on loadString
    var document = xml.parse(contents);
    xmlBody = document.findAllElements('string');
    print("load finish");
    print("I can wait rootBundle here");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same answer as given by @CopsOnRoad with some explanation.

You should separate the use of future response `rootBundle.loadString()`.

try following:

```dart
 String contents = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/i18n/en/strings.xml');
 var document = xml.parse(contents);
 xmlBody = document.findAllElements('string');
 print("load finish");
```

**Note**: you'll need to add `async` modifier in all methods, even in the main method as well and add `await` before every method call.

i.e.:

```dart
void main(){
...
  await inter.init();
...
}


...

Future<void> init async {
 String contents = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/i18n/en/strings.xml');
 var document = xml.parse(contents);
 xmlBody = document.findAllElements('string');
 print("load finish");
}
```